# Find a number in a list of numbers using Java8 sterams

Tags: java-8

I have a list of numbers

```
List<Integer> tensOfMinutes = Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60);
```

I'm trying to determine if an input int `Integer minutes;` is between any two members of the array above.

**Example:** for an input `Integer minutes = 23;` I expect to get *20* as an answer.

Any ideas for how to accomplish this while iterating a stream of *tensOfMinutes* ?

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to be already sorted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)
        .stream()
        .filter( (i) -> i<23 )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println( l.get( l.size() - 1 ) );
```

You filter out all elements bigger than `23` and you print the last one of the remaining elements.

It would have been easier with the `dropWhile` function that we have in Java 9, Scala and Haskell:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-

---

**Improved version by Holger**

```
    Stream<Integer> stream = Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60).stream();
    stream.filter( i -> i<23 )
      .reduce( (a,b) -> b )
      .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

You can see the `(a,b) -> b` lambda used to ger the last element and the `ifPresent` method used to make it error safe.

Comment: `l.stream().filter(i -> i<23).reduce((a,b) -> b).ifPresent(System.out::println);` or if the elements are not pre-sorted use `.reduce(Math::max)` instead of `.reduce((a,b) -> b)`… Btw, I don’t see how `dropWhile` would make anything easier.

Comment: @Holger great solution using reduce

Answer (score 0):

List list=IntStream.of(10,20,6,7,81).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: This question already contains multiple answers and an accepted answer. Can you explain (by editing your answer) where your answer differs from the other answers? Also know that Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score -2):

You will want the number before the first larger number so try this:

```
int previous=0
for(Integer number : tensOfMinutes)
    if(number<=numberToFind)
        previous=number;
```

You will cycle through all numbers and remember the last one that was smaller or equal to the number youre searching for in the variable `previous`. This expects the list to be sorted in ascending order. I don't know the exact specs of the integer class but that's the way of approach

Comment: The question asks (in both title and the body) specifically about using a stream.